# Can't get checkboxgroup to work propperly in my vaadin form

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Let me be the first to say that DBA's should not be doing programming on their spare time, they should stay in place. Sorry I didn't listen!

So I made a simple java project for myself. It basically is gonna end up as a "quite outdated movie rental thingy" built on Java and Vaadin.

What I cannot figure out on how to do, is to get my "movie entering form" to work properly. I have two pojos, Movie and MovieGenre, they have a many-to-many relation, seems fair. But I cannot get the setup in the form to work. I've tried a few different "multi-select" components, but can get non of them to work, because I am not doing it right...

So I need a pointer to what I am missing here... Could it be some sort of a listener och some conversion between my MovieGenre-objects to "something boolean"? I've checked that the Set is there as the form opens via a simple print statement. And it is. Problem is that I am not swift enough to figure out how to get my Movie's genres to work with those checkboxes...

Thanks for your time spent!

Movie.java extract:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "movie_id_seq")
  private Long id;
  @NotEmpty
  private String title;
  @NotEmpty
  @Column(length = 1000)
  private String description;
  private LocalDate releaseDate;
  private LocalDate dateAdded;
  @Range(min = 0, max = 20)
  private Integer numberInStock;
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "movie_moviegenre", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "moviegenre_id") })
  private Set<MovieGenre> movieGenres;

--getters, setters, constuctors
```

MovieGenre.java extract:

```
@Entity
public class MovieGenre {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "moviegenre_id_seq")
  private Integer id;
  @NotEmpty
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String genre;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movieGenres")
  private Set<Movie> movies;

--getters, setters, constructors, toString
```

MovieForm.java extract:

```
public class MovieForm extends FormLayout {
  Binder<Movie> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Movie.class);
  private Movie movie;

--some form elements
  CheckboxGroup<MovieGenre> genres = new CheckboxGroup<>();
--some more form elements

  public MovieForm(Set<MovieGenre> movieGenres) {
    addClassNames("movie-form", "form");
    binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

    genres.setLabel("Genres");
    genres.setItems(movieGenres);
    genres.setItemLabelGenerator(MovieGenre::getGenre);
    // genres.addValueChangeListener();

    // FIXME: This does not work, boxes don't get checked... or saved for that
    // matter
    // binder.forField(genres).bind(Movie::getMovieGenres, Movie::setMovieGenres);

    add(
        title,
        configureDescription(),
        genres,
        releaseDate,
        dateAdded,
        configureNumberInStock(),
        createButtonLayout());
  }
```

Comment: Hi. I have done this at work but do not have access to that code at the moment. One difference is that I wrote the binding myself but I cannot see why it should not work atm. Are you able to share your code so I can test it? Preferably something like Github.

Comment: Shot in the dark: you don't have the equasl and hashCode functions implemented for the MovieGenre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Avec and @cfrick you both lead me right.
I needed to implement both the overrides of `hashCode` and `equals`, both of their purposes that I now understand better and realize that I should have looked into better.
But then also I needed to bind the `checkboxgroup` by hand with:

```
binder.forField(genres).bind(Movie::getMovieGenres, Movie::setMovieGenres);
```

So thanks a lot. Your comments was all it took. Great!

Comment: Remember to mark your answer as accepted too :)